# adding subviews to an NSView to have a chess-like grid

Tags: cocoa, nsview, subview, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to create a Cocoa UI that consists of two sets of squares (chess-like grids) that will assume different colours while an underlying algorithm is running. When the execution of the algorithm comes to an end, the UI should be able to handle clicks, panning and other gestures.

The hierarchy I have so far is the following (please check the attached code for specifics):

1) the main window that is the window of a window controller

2) a split view with two custom views, mainView and sideView (each one would hold a set of squares)

3) two view controllers (mainViewController and sideViewController)

I would like to be able to load the squares as subviews of mainView and sideView.

I thought of having another custom view, say SquareView with another nib file. My questions would be:

a) how do I create this SquareView so that it can be used to create the squares that will be added to mainView and sideView as subviews to form chess-like grids?

b) how do I add subviews to mainView and sideView to built the two grids? For the sake of simplicity, let's assume there would be four non-overlapping squares for each of the previously mentioned views.

Thank you!

---

MainView.m

```
#import "MainView.h"


@implementation MainView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)TheRect 
{
    [[NSColor grayColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:[self bounds]];
}
```

SideView.m

```
#import "SideView.h"


@implementation MainView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)TheRect 
{
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:[self bounds]];
}
```

MainWindowController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class SideViewController;
@class MainViewController;

@interface MainWindowController : NSWindowController 
{
    IBOutlet NSSplitView* oMainSplitView;
    SideViewController* sideViewController;
    MainViewController* mainViewController;

}

@end
```

MainWindowController.m

```
#import "MainWindowController.h"
#import "SideViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad
{

   sideViewController = [[SideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SideView" bundle:nil];
   NSView* splitViewLeftView = [[oMainSplitView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
   NSView* sideView = [sideViewController view];
   [sideView setFrame:[splitViewLeftView bounds]];
   [sideView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
   [splitViewLeftView addSubview:sideView];

   mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
   NSView* splitViewRightView = [[oMainSplitView subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
   NSView* mainView = [mainViewController view];
   [mainView setFrame:[splitViewRightView bounds]];
   [mainView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
   [splitViewRightView addSubview:mainView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a) I think the easiest way would be to create a matrix of NSBoxes, which you could do in code or in IB.  Having the squares in a matrix would make it easy to loop through them or access specific ones.

b) I'm not sure what your question is here -- you would do it just as you did in your posted code, using [mainView addSubview:squareMatrix];

After Edit: Actually, it looks like IB won't let you embed NSBoxes in a matrix.  In the past, I've made a matrix of subclassed NSButtonCells (to allow background color with no border) that had a grid of 64x64 cells that were clickable and would change color with those clicks.  I don't know if you want a fixed number of cells in your views, or do you need to dynamically change the number? Something like this could work for you I think -- I actually created this in code, because IB was really slow in updating with that many cells.

Here is what I did. In my case, I needed cells with no border but with background color, so I had to subclass NSButtonCell, like this:

```
-(id)initWithRGBAlpha:(NSArray *)rgbAlpha {
    if (self == [super init]) {
    NSColor *color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:[[rgbAlpha objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue]
                                               green:[[rgbAlpha objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue] 
                                                blue:[[rgbAlpha objectAtIndex:2]doubleValue] 
                                               alpha:[[rgbAlpha objectAtIndex:3]doubleValue]];
    [self setBackgroundColor:color];
    [self setTitle:@""];
    [self setBordered:NO];
    [self setTag:0];
    [self setImageScaling:3];
    return self;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}

-(void) setState:(NSInteger)value {
    if (value == 1) {
        self.backgroundColor = self.selectedColor;
        [super setState:value];
    }else {
        self.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
        [super setState:value];
    }
}


-(void) setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)color {
    backgroundColor = color;
    selectedColor = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:.75];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.backgroundColor forKey:@"bColor"]; 
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    self.backgroundColor = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bColor"];
    return self;
}
```

I created the matrix in code, like so:

```
@implementation RDMatrix

-(void) initWithParentView:(NSView *) cv {
    NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:one,one,one,one,nil];
    RDButtonCell *theCell = [[RDButtonCell alloc ]initWithRGBAlpha:colors];
    [self initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200,100,1,1) mode:2 prototype:theCell numberOfRows:64 numberOfColumns:64]; 
    [self setSelectionByRect:TRUE];
    [self setCellSize:NSMakeSize(8,8)];
    [self sizeToCells];
    self.target = self;
    self.action = @selector(matrixClick:);
    self.backgroundColor = [NSColor lightGrayColor];
    self.drawsBackground = TRUE;
    self.autoresizingMask = 8;
    self.allowsEmptySelection = TRUE;
    [cv addSubview:self]; 
}

-(void) matrixClick: (id) sender {
    for  (RDButtonCell *aCell in self.selectedCells){
        if ([self.selectedCells count] < 64) {
             aCell.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
        }else{
        aCell.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:.5 blue:1 alpha:1];
        }
    }
    [self deselectAllCells];
}
@end
```

Comment: Why would using `NSBox`'s be easier/better than just drawing the squares in a custom view?

Comment: @trojanfoe, I don't know about "better", but I think it's easier to do in IB, since you can lay it out the way you want it to look, and NSBoxes (of the custom type) give you both border and fill colors. Ultimately (for me), it comes down to convenience (of doing it in IB) vs. flexibility of doing it in code.

Comment: I might not have been clear enough and I apologize for that. The idea is to add a grid of squares to each of the views (mainView and sideView). Each square will assume different colours as the algorithms runs. Later trackpad gestures would have to be handled by the application. I really do not know which way to go. Should I have a nib file with a square that would be loaded to create an array of child views? In this case would I need another view controller for the child views? Or would it be better to use NSCollectionView, CALayers, NSBoxes or NSButtons? What if I have 100+ squares? Thx!

Comment: Well, I stand by the idea in my original post (but see my edited answer, for a correction).  Your further explanation doesn't make me think it couldn't work, so I don't know what you think I'm not understanding about your question.

Comment: The number of squares in the grid will not change over time. The squares would just change colours and be amenable to trackpad gestures after the algorithm is done. 1) Do you think you could provide me with some lines of code regarding the creation of that 64x64 grid of cells? 2) Would the grid be subordinated to the mainView controller or require something analogous? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this as simple or as complicated as you desire: simple? do everything you want in MainView's drawRect method; complex: nest NSViews (or NSCell's, or NSBox's, etc.) and have each one draw itself.

Personally, I'd vote to keep it simple…